# How to include acr_values in Passport authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, identityserver4

I have Passport set up and working using an oauth2 strategy (code flow) against Identity Server 4. I need to include acr_values in the call to the Identity Server (this is working from another client correctly).

My understanding (as shown [here](https://codeburst.io/how-to-implement-openid-authentication-with-openid-client-and-passport-in-node-js-43d020121e87) for example) is that the following code should add acr_values to the auth call:

```
app.get('/auth', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('oidc', { acr_values: 'urn:grn:authn:fi:all' })(req, res, next);
});
```

But this doesn't work. Running the code from that sample also doesn't work.

Is this something I'm doing wrong, or has it changed?

How can I have passport include acr_values in the call to the Identity Server?

Answer (score 1):

The `acr_values` format you use is not valid, it must be a single string which is space separated like: `acr_1 acr_2 tenant:tenant_value idp:idp_value`

Per [Docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/token.html?highlight=acr_values#token-endpoint):

> acr_values
> allows passing in additional authentication related information - identityserver special cases the following proprietary acr_values:

> idp:name_of_idp bypasses the login/home realm screen and forwards the user directly to the selected identity provider (if allowed per client configuration)

> tenant:name_of_tenant can be used to pass a tenant name to the login UI

Here is where in code it gets validated: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Validation/Default/AuthorizeRequestValidator.cs#L771

Example in tests: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/test/IdentityServer.IntegrationTests/Endpoints/Authorize/JwtRequestAuthorizeTests.cs#L667